# CSS: Difference between Tag.class and .class Tag

Tags: css

What is the difference between these two CSS entries:

```
a.special {
    color: #296596;
    font-family: "Georgia";
}
```

and

```
.special a {
    color: #296596;
    font-family: "Georgia";
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- `a.special` targets an `a` element with the class `special` on itself.
- `.special a` targets an `a` element *somewhere at any depth* within an element that has the class `special`.

This is very basic knowledge, I would recommend starting [with a tutorial on the subject](http://learnwebcode.com/basic-css-selectors/).